# In r, How to get the list of names that exist in another list

Tags: r, list

```
set1 <- c("Dallas", "Plano", "Frisco")

set2 <- c("Dallas", "SF", "NewYork")
```

I want to find out the elements that exist in both the lists set1 and set2. I tried 
`set1 %in% set2`, but its not solving the problem.

output expected as

```
set3 <- c("Dallas")
```

Comment: Try `intersect(set1, set2)`. Also, `set1[set1 %in% set2]`.

Comment: It works. Thank you @RuiBarradas